# SVG space around

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg icon which is generated by some plugin used in the project. I need to modify the svg because it has some blank space around. 
How to fix this? What causes that blank space ?

[image]

```
[https://codepen.io/zoom/pen/NEObQB][2]
```

Comment: please add your code to quetion

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand your question. Please try `viewBox="53 22 26 36"` for your SVG element. The values used are taken from your triangle bounding box

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `width` and `height` also to `svg` **instead**:

```
 x="8" y="22" viewBox="0 0 125 80"  style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);  stroke-width: 0px;"
```

```html
<div>
  <svg id="svg"  width="125" height="60"><rect fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" width="125" height="60"></rect><polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="red" points="53,22 53,58 79,40"></polygon></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your SVG to be scalable according to the height and width set on it's parent div, set it up like this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <svg id="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 125 80" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);  stroke-width: 0px;"><rect fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" width="125" height="80"></rect><polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="red" points="53,22 53,58 79,40"></polygon></svg>
</div>

<div class="div2">
  <svg id="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 125 80" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);  stroke-width: 0px;"><rect fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="none" width="125" height="80"></rect><polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="red" points="53,22 53,58 79,40"></polygon></svg>
</div>
```